# Match a zero followed by 6 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to match a zero followed by a dot and exactly 6 digits. Such as --> 0.274538

The 6 digits can be any number 0-9. Also, any characters (including blank spaces) may exist before or after the match.

I would like to trim the tailing 4 digits off of the match, so that the result is a zero followed by 2 decimal places (ie 0.27).

I'm using this regex inside a Javascript string replace function. I'm including the "g" modifier, as there will be several matches within the string.

I'm not very good with regex, but I think the following code is pretty close to what I need...

```
var replaced = string.replace(/[0]\.[0-9]{6}$/g, X);
```

Only thing is... I'm not sure what to use for the 'replace' value here (X). If there was only one match expected, then I could just use "slice" on the replaced string. But since I am expecting several regex matches in the string, what should I use for the "X" value? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Could you please precise *any characters (including blank spaces) may exist before or after the match*? Can those be letters or underscores? If yes, `\b`-based solution won't help.

Comment: Yes, these characters may include letters, numbers, underscores, etc.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: can you have this input - `Word_0.654567_0.675456`?

Comment: Actually, on second thought... it would be pretty easy for me to modify my code so that the only possible characters to be expected before or after the match would be commas, round brackets, or blank spaces. So if the answers here would work in that scenario, then I'm good to go!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use capturing group:

```
var s = '0.274538'
var r = s.replace(/\b(0\.\d{2})\d{4}\b/g, '$1');
//=> 0.27
```

- `\b` is for word boundary.
- `(..)` is captured group #1 to grab `0` followed by a DOT and 2 decimal point.
- `$1` is back-reference of captured group#1

Comment: I didn't know about capturing groups. Perfect and succinct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing it, with a `function` as a the replace parameter:

```js
var regex = /0\.\d{6}/g;
var num = '0.543456';

var trimmed = num.replace(regex, function(match){
  return match.substr(0, match.length - 4);
  });

console.log(trimmed);
```

Comment: Great to know there is more than one way to do this. Thank you!